# Is it possible to call child method from abstract?

Tags: javascript, typescript

There is a abstract class:

```
abstract class MenuItemBase implements MenuItem {
   constructor() {
       stream$.subscribe(() => {
          this.activate();
       });
   }
}
```

Concrete child class is:

```
export class MenuLayer extends MenuItemBase {
   activate(): void {
       // Call concrete realization
   }
}
```

Is it possible to call child method `this.activate();` from abstract when data is comming?

I have moved stream to the abstract class because it were duplicates in each child class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if you make the method as part of your `abstract` class (or inherit from something that does.

```
abstract class MenuItemBase implements MenuItem {
   constructor() {
       stream$.subscribe(() => {
          this.activate();
       });
   }
   // here:
   abstract activate(): void;
   // or
   activate(): void { this.active = true; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if all child classes have the same code in own activate implementation: `activate() { this.active = true; // Different logic }`. Where `this.active = true;` duplicate code in each child class.

Comment: @AlexandraBalmush then don't make it abstract. override it as needed.

Comment: Yes, I do, but in this case not working your solution.

Comment: @AlexandraBalmush then that sounds like a _new_ question. explain why it isn't working.